Pergola Rafter Alignment
I'm in FLORIDA and working on my first 12x24 pergola with 6 posts. The long side includes three 6x6 posts 12 ft away from each other. The short side includes two 6x6 posts 12 ft away from each other.
Details:

6x6 Severe Weather #2 Southern Yellow Pine Ground Contact Pressure Treated Lumber
Double 2*8 beam on Long and Shirt Sides
Rafters 2x6x12 aligned North to South parallel to the short side

I want to Lay the rafters Flat instead of standing on edge.
Wanted to get people's thoughts on the rafter sizes to ensure I don't get any sagging. If needed I would like to run support in the middle parallel to the long side.
Attached is the picture for reference. I am planning to build a similar structure but on concrete footings. Rafters are the question.

To combat sagging, only the height matters, not width.  A 2x4 or 2x6 laid flat will give the same protection against sagging as a 2x2 (or a 1x2 on edge).  People could use more data about why you want to lay the rafters flat and what you hope to gain by doing so.

Why do you want to lay the rafters flat?

Thought that would create more shade than the conventional method. Now I understand why they are laid on the edge to avoid Sagging.
